# Changing label color when printing by each line using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

When I print the map, I want to show more than one feature of the element under its dimension, but in different colors.

For example, the first line should appear in blue and the second line in green.

I can display the numbers under each other with the code "chr (13)", but I need to change the color for each line.

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: If the lines are stacked on top of each other you will only be able to see the top-most line, no matter what colors they are. Have you considered making three side by side maps, one for each layer/color?

Comment: Read this to the end https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/about-building-label-expressions.htm